# No certificate after adding tde on rds

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

We have RDS SQL server running and added tde to the option group. However, RDS didn't generate the certificate. Any idea why? Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Restart the RDS gave me the certificate from
select name from sys.certificates where name like 'RDSTDECertificate%';

Thanks.